# how to correctly fit an html table onto a page?

Tags: html

I'm trying to align a calculator I coded to fit onto a web page but am looking for better html practices to achieve my task. For example, there are 155px margins on the left and right and I want to fit my table between those margains.

Here is the page I am trying to fix: http://macrorevolution.com/bmr/

Here is an example of my table settings I am using:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: bmrcalc
*/
?>



<?php get_header(); ?>



<?php $al_options = get_option('al_general_settings');?>



<!-- Title -->

<div class="box pt20">

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="headertext">

        <?php the_title() ?>

        <?php $headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_headline", $single = false);?>

        <?php if(!empty($headline[0]) ):?>

            <span><?php echo $headline[0] ?></span>

        <?php endif?>

    </div>

    <div class="clearsmall"></div>



    <!-- Promo text -->

    <?php $promo = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_promo", $single = false);?>

    <?php if(!empty($promo[0]) ):?>

       <div class="calloutcontainer">

            <div class="container_12">

                <div class="grid_12">            

                    <?php echo do_shortcode($promo[0]);?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>    

    <?php endif?>

    <div class="container_12">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<?php
$answer = "";
$agev = "";
$feetv = "";
$inchesv = "";
$weightv = "";
$sex = "";
if(isset($_POST['agev']) && isset($_POST['feetv']) && isset($_POST['inchesv']) && isset($_POST['weightv']) && isset($_POST['sex'])) {
    $agev = $_POST['agev'];
    $feetv = $_POST['feetv'];
    $inchesv = $_POST['inchesv'];
    $weightv = $_POST['weightv'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $totalheightv = $inchesv + ($feetv*12);
    $heightcm = $totalheightv*2.54;
    $weightkg = $weightv/2.2;
    if($sex=='male') $answer = 66.47 + (13.75*$weightkg) + (5*$heightcm) - (6.75*$agev);
    if($sex=='female') $answer = 665.09 + (9.56*$weightkg) + (1.84*$heightcm) - (4.67*$agev);

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Basal Metabolic Rate Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action=''>
<table border='5' width='100%'  class="table" style="margin: 0 auto;" bgcolor="FFFFFF">

    <tr class="calcheading">
        <td colspan="2">MacroRevolution BMR Calculator</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='agev' value="<?php echo $agev; ?>"/>Years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow2">
        <td>Height:</td>
        <td align="justify"><input type='text' name='feetv' value="<?php echo $feetv; ?>"/>Ft<input type='text' name='inchesv' value="<?php echo $inchesv; ?>"/>In</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>Weight:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type='text' name='weightv' value="<?php echo $weightv; ?>"/>lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gender">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male
                        <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="submit">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td colspan="2">Your BMR is <span style="background-color: #00CC33"><?php echo $answer?></span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>

<table border='0' width='100%' class="table" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">
    <h4 style="background: #99FF99;">
<strong>BMR = Basal Metabolic Rate</strong> (similar to RMR = Resting Metabolic Rate). Your BMR represents the number of calories your body burns at rest. Regular routine of cardiovascular exercise can increase your BMR, improving your health and fitness when your body's ability to burn energy gradually slows down.
    </h4>
    </td>
</table>
<table border='0' width='50%' class="table" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">

    <h2 style="background: #99FF66;">Formula for BMR</h2>
    <h4 style="background: #99FF66;">
    If you want to manually calculate your BMR, use the (<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris%E2%80%93Benedict_equation">Harris-Benedict formula</a>) <br> below. <br><br>
Men: BMR=66.47+ (13.75 x W) + (5.0 x H) - (6.75 x A) <br>
Women: BMR=665.09 + (9.56 x W) + (1.84 x H) - (4.67 x A) <br><br>

    W = Weight in kilograms (lbs/2.2)<br>
    H = Height in centimeters (inches x 2.54)<br>
    A = Age in years
    </h4>
    </td>
</table>


</body>
</html>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thats not a data table. Don't use a table for this.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
width = '50%'
```

and

```
margin-left: 155px;
margin-right: 155px;
```

use the following `style` for the table with `class='table'`:

```
width = '100%'
```

and

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Thanks IamDesai, so I applied "margin: 0 auto;" to all my tables. Check out http://macrorevolution.com/bmr/    How can I fill/stretch my tables to fit the appropriate margains? Check out the page to see what I mean

Comment: Using your updated changes stretches the tables across entire screen as shown on http://macrorevolution.com/bmr/  Any suggestion?

Comment: @RyanGoo Are you sure you have updated the code at your end? I do not see any changes at my end. Also, if you think my answer solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I applied the code to the first 2 tables, And they stretch all the way across the screen, I want the tables to fit between the 155px margins on the left and right (refer to http://macrorevolution.com/bmr/) to see desired margins. I will mark your answer as best soon

Comment: It is not a good idea to hardcode the margins since deifferent people use different screen resolutions and browser window sizes. In my opinion, you should use `margin: 0 auto;` and set `width = '70%'` for the content to look proper.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. So there is no way to have width 100% that will end at the margins?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Refer to http://imgur.com/Qz8VcEY , The background is a striped greyish color that eventually turns white (Marked by red line). Ideally, I want the tables to be lined up with the margins (marked by blue line) for any resolution. Is this possible?

Comment: Place the `<form>` inside `<div class="box pt20">`. This should fix it.

Comment: Thanks man! that seemed to do the trick. Mind explaining what <div class="box pt20"> does ?? I am unfamiliar with this.

Comment: Think of `<div class="box pt20">` as a HTML container where you initially had only the black bar with BMR on it. So we are now just adding the `<form>` to this container. Since the container has it margins set already, it gets automatically applied to the `<form>`. Cheers!